# How to efficiently merge two lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, random-access

There are several ways to merge lists in Java

- You can call to `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`
- You can use the stream API, like `Stream.concat()` or `Stream.of(listA, listB).forEach()`
- and more...

What would be the most memory and performance efficient way to merge two random access lists into a new random access list?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "merge"?

Comment: @Bohemian Probably combine into one `List`.

Comment: @Bohemian for the input of two random access lists, I need an output of one random access-list with all of the elements of the provided lists, the order is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to create an immutable list containing all the elements, by performing a shallow copy. Beware that changes to the source lists will be reflected in the resulting list (so the immutability in reality depends on the immutability / access to the input lists).

```
public class MergedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private final List<T>[] lists;
    private final int size;

    @SafeVarargs
    MergedList(List<T>... lists) {
        this.lists = lists.clone();
        this.size = Arrays.stream(lists).mapToInt(list -> list.size()).sum();
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        for (List<T> list : lists)
            if (index < list.size())
                return list.get(index);
            else
                index -= list.size();
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index");
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

and

```
List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> b = List.of(5, 6, 7);
List<Integer> c = new MergedList<>(a, b);
System.out.println(c);
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Considering that the original list is updated, it might be better to remove the field `size` and do this:

```
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Arrays.stream(lists).mapToInt(list -> list.size()).sum();
    }
```

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: This is also incomplete. You should implement all methods. Also, this code: `this.lists = lists.clone();` uses just as much memory and more processing than just adding one  list to the other.

Comment: @Bohemian The superclass `AbstractList<T>` implements `List<T>`, so it satisfies the list requirement. However, `set(int, T)` throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. It's similar to a list created with `List.of`. Override if necessary. Since `lists.clone()` is a shallow copy of the list array, it does not copy the elements of the list specified by the argument.

Comment: So if I were to call say `addAll(someList)` on an instance of your class it would work as expected?

Comment: @Bohemian It is similar to the list created with `List.of`. If you say it's not a list, `MergedList` is not a list.

Comment: @Bohemian From `AbstractList`: "To implement an unmodifiable list, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the `get(int)` and `size()` methods."

Comment: @MaartenBodewes OP did not not specify unmodifiable. Maybe better to name this class `UnmodifiableMergedList`.

Comment: Well, since the answer was accepted, I guess it was not a breaking point either. And that's why I added the description on top. I'm not sure about the name change as it doesn't guarantee that the list doesn't change (OTOH, elements may change value as well if they are mutable). I would see this trick used for methods that require a list to be supplied as parameter that don't require modification. Not copying is always faster and more memory efficient than copying the elements I suppose (although copying references from an `ArrayList` wont take forever either).

Comment: @Bohemian It's a bit strange to me that you keep arguing while the bad arguments in the comments that you are made are still present. With the edit, they are not required anymore. I think both answers are useful and can coexist.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it was accepted presumably because OP is OK with an unmodifiable implementation (even though not stating that). As for being "unmodifiable", the class is designed as such, even if its internals are mutable - that just makes it an unsafe implementation because it doesn't make safe copies of the lists, but that's the whole point so it's fine. I think this is a fine implementation for an unmodifiable list. It's just that the user of the class needs to be aware of that, otherwise they could be sad if they try to modify it.

Answer (score 6):

you can use [Apache commons library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html)-

```
ListUtils.union(listA, listB);
```

Using parallel Java8 Streams could be is better instead of just streams for large datasets.

```
Stream.concat(list1.parallelStream(), list1.parallelStream())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `parallelStream` use multi-threading which will break the orinigal list order, this should be noticed.

Answer (score 5):

You have not defined what "merge" means in your context. This answer assumes it means "combine into one list".

To reduce the amount of memory and processing used, create a List whose size is exactly right, then add each list in turn to it.

```
List<E> result = new ArrayList<>(list1.size() + list2.size());
result.addAll(list1);
result.addAll(list2);
```

This eliminates possible redundant memory allocation and object creation that may occur during `list1.addAll(list2)`.

Comment: I don't think this is the best possible solution as it requires o(n) space. I believe there is an o(1) space solution(not including the input), that somehow map the indexes to the existing lists.

Comment: @IlyaGazman I suppose you could write a wrapper class that implements `List` and wraps two lists, delegating to the wrapped lists based on the index and combining the lists for methods like `size()` and `stream()`. You would really have to want to do this to bother - are you sure it's not micro optimization that not worth the effort?

Comment: Good point! I hoped that there is something native in Java for that. I will double-check if this is indeed worse the effort. Tnx!

Comment: If order is not important, then this is the way to go.  On the other hand, if you are done with the original lists.  Just add one to the other.